# Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long for https in nginx on ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, nginx, https

am using rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9 for my app, have to run application in https with domain name like https://welcome.com on my system. so i configure my nginx by creating ssl certificate for domain name and https

snapshort of ssl:

```
# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
server_name welcome.com;

root html;
index index.html index.htm;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout 5m;
}
```

i can able to saw nginx home page by calling welcome.com and https://welcome.com. without running the rails application

My application also running in port 443 successfully, but after querying in browser like https://welcome.com

Rails terminal showing error:

```
 ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\
 ERROR bad URI `._i\b8\x10�yA�^6�v�M|
```

In browser throwing error:

```
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

Even tried by clearing browser history repeatedly, but the result is same.

Am not sure what i made wrong, can any one help  me?

have i made any wrong in certificate creation ?

Comment: I've found another source of this error is if you have "listen 443;" but not "listen 443 ssl;" http://serverfault.com/a/497433/45814

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have both `listen 443 ssl;` *and* `ssl on;`, remove the `ssl on;` line and restart nginx.